# state is not being updated when using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently playing around with the new React Hooks feature, and I have run into an issue where the state of a functional component is not being updated even though I believe I am doing everything correctly, another pair of eyes on this test app would be much appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const TodoList = () => {
  let updatedList = useTodoListState({ 
    title: "task3", completed: false 
  });
const renderList = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        updatedList.map((item) => {
          <React.Fragment key={item.title}>
            <p>{item.title}</p>
          </React.Fragment>
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
return renderList();
}

function useTodoListState(state) {
  const [list, updateList] = useState([
    { title: "task1", completed: false },
    { title: "task2", completed: false }
  ]);
  useEffect(() => {
    updateList([...list, state]);
  })
  return list;
}

export default TodoList;
```

updateList in useTodoListState's useEffect function should be updating the list variable to hold three pieces of data, however, that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here:

1. In `renderList` you are misusing `React.Fragment`. It should be used to wrap multiple DOM nodes so that the component only returns a single node. You are wrapping individual paragraph elements each in their own Fragment.
2. Something needs to be returned on each iteration of a `map`. This means you need to use the `return` keyword. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39629962/4881192) for more about arrow function syntax.)
3. Your code will update infinitely because `useEffect` is updating its own hook's state. To remedy this, you need to include an array as a second argument in `useEffect` that will tell React to only use that effect if the given array changes.

Here's what it should all look like (with some reformatting):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const TodoList = () => {
  let updatedList = useTodoListState({
    title: "task3", completed: false
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment> // #1: use React.Fragment to wrap multiple nodes
      {
        updatedList.map((item) => {
          return <p key={item.title}>{item.title}</p> // #2: return keyword inside map with braces
        })
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

function useTodoListState(state) {
  const [list, updateList] = useState([
    { title: "task1", completed: false },
    { title: "task2", completed: false }
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    updateList([...list, state]);
  }, [...list]) // #3: include a second argument to limit the effect

  return list;
}

export default TodoList;
```

Edit:
Although I have tested that the above code works, it would ultimately be best to rework the structure to remove `updateList` from `useEffect` or implement another variable to control updating.

Comment: will using `[...list]` as second arg to `useEffect` have different behaviour to just using `[list]`?

Comment: @lecstor Yes. The second argument should contain any values from the outer scope that are used inside `useEffect`. Here, the list array is being spread, so the list array in the effect limiter needs to be spread as well.

Comment: hmm.. It's more that `useEffect` will only run if any values in that array have changed (except the first time), so I don't see how there would be any difference. Unless of course you mutated the list, changing one of it's items without changing the actual list object which is not what `updateList` would do.

Comment: I agree with that, but when I tested this, the update ran infinitely without array spread.

Comment: hmm.. I get `Warning: The final argument passed to useEffect changed size between renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant.` https://codesandbox.io/s/9lw4wo1jqr

Comment: and, yeh, it killed my codesandbox without the spread, but that's because `list` is being updated by `useEffect` so it keeps getting triggered. It's just the nature of the test app that is wrong.

Comment: @ayaz-uddin, I'd say, for the current implementation, an empty array should be used as the second arg to `useEffect`. (for a rather different implementation see https://codesandbox.io/s/wow5q2k9kk)

Comment: Ultimately, it would be better to either implement another variable to control updating or rework the structure to remove updating from `useEffect` altogether.