# Arrow function syntax with parentheses instead of curly braces?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I saw a code snippet in a React tutorial:

```
const App = ({title}) => (
  <div className="header">{title}</div>
);
```

At first glance, I thought it assigned an arrow function to the `App` constant. Then I noticed it doesn't use curly braces but parentheses.

I understand arrow function should be `(...) => {...}`, but here it uses `(...) => (...)`

So, is it an arrow function or not? If it is, why there is another form? How can I decide when to use which form? If it isn't, what's this function type called in js?

Comment: It's an implicity return.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Why not? 3. It's up to you, the braces are only required if you can't immediately return a value. 4. N/A.

Comment: `(...args) => expr` is equivalent to `(...args) => { return expr; }` — a shortcut for a commonly used format.

Comment: Have you checked the [arrow functions documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's also an arrow function. The only difference, is that if you don't use braces, it forces a return:

```
const App = () => { return true; } // with braces you've to use the return statement

const App = () => true; // without braces it forces the return statement automatically
```

The [MDN arrow function expression documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body) says the following about this:

> #### Function body
>
> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block
> body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the
> implicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit
> `return` statement.
>
> ```
> var func = x => x * x;
> // concise body syntax, implied "return"
>
> var func = (x, y) => { return x + y; };
> // with block body, explicit "return" needed
> ```

Furthermore, with regard to the parentheses: the arrow function in this case returns a **JSX expression**, which is considered a single object.
Parentheses are mostly used for multi-line JSX code. See more information here: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html
and also the other similar question on Stack overflow.

Comment: The second form is also only available for a single expression — you cannot use statements.

Comment: @Amadan 's comment completes the answer. Good point there.

Comment: If my arrow function has multiple lines of logics before returning, should I use curly braces or parenthesis? Could you please give a direct answer to this question?

Comment: @Leem in that case you clearly don't have a choice; you *must* use braces, as you need the *body* of the function not just a return value.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the syntax:

```
const a = ({ foo }) => ( <Component /> );
```

This means that the code inside the brackets is inherently returned. I.e., the fat arrow the return is forced. Whereas this syntax:

```
const b = ({ bar }) => {
  some();
  thing();
};
```

This would indicate actions performed, but nothing is returned. Ie the 'return' keyword must be present for anything to be returned from the function, like this:

```
const c = ({ baz }) => { return <AnotherComponent />; }
```

The first and third examples with a return (implicit or otherwise) would be useful for reusable functions and/or components. The middle one where nothing is returned would be more useful for state management (mobx/redux/flux for example) where you'd need to implement HOF or functions that return state or objects.