# Data fetched from an API is not rendering (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm tryng to make an api call and store the data in a variable using react hooks (useEffect). The data gets stored in an array, but when I want to render it, nothing gets rendered.

```
    const [cards, setCards] = useState<ICard[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
        if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Couldnt find the url');
        setCards(initCards(await response.json()));
        console.log(cards);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message);
        // TODO: Show error alert
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const initCards = (cards: Cats[]): ICard[] => {
    let minifiedCards: ICard[] = [];
    for (const card of cards) {
      const { id, url } = card;
      minifiedCards.push({ id, image: url, touched: false });
    }
    console.log(minifiedCards);

    return minifiedCards;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ScoreBoard />
      {loading ? 'loading...' : <p>loaded</p>}
      <CardsGrid cards={cards} />
    </div>
  );
const CardsGrid = ({ cards }: CardsGridProps) => (
  <div className="card-grid">
    <h2>Cards Grid</h2>
    {cards.map((card) => {
      card.id;
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Can you share the whole component?

Comment: `const [cards, setCards] = useState<ICard[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
        if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Couldnt find the url');
        setCards(initCards(await response.json()));
        console.log(cards);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message);
        // TODO: Show error alert
      }
    })();
  }, []);return (
    <div className="App">
      <CardsGrid cards={cards} />
    </div>
  );`

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know how to add code in comments

Comment: Comments aren't really for entire code snippets, you can edit your question to include any new details though.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks, I've already edited the question to include the whole component (the only thing missing is the api url)

Comment: So are you saying that `CardsGrid` isn't rerendering with the updated `cards` state passed in props? Can you update your question to include the `CardsGrid` component code?

Comment: Yes. I've added the component to the question

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You don't return anything to render in the `CardsGrid` component when mapping the `cards` prop array.

```
const CardsGrid = ({ cards }: CardsGridProps) => (
  <div className="card-grid">
    <h2>Cards Grid</h2>
    {cards.map((card) => {
      card.id; // <-- nothing returned/mapped to JSX
    })}
  </div>
);
```

## Solution

Return valid JSX from the map callback. Don't forget to include React keys. Here is about the simplest/minimal example.

```
const CardsGrid = ({ cards }: CardsGridProps) => (
  <div className="card-grid">
    <h2>Cards Grid</h2>
    {cards.map((card) => {
      return (
        <Fragment key={card.id}>
          {card.id}
        </Fragment>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

You can also ***implicitly*** return JSX. Note there is no function body enclosed in curly brackets (`{}`). (*`() => { return value; }` vs `() => value`*)

```
const CardsGrid = ({ cards }: CardsGridProps) => (
  <div className="card-grid">
    <h2>Cards Grid</h2>
    {cards.map((card) => (
      <Fragment key={card.id}>
        {card.id}
      </Fragment>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: It's probably cleaner to change `(card) => { return ( ... ) }` into `(card) => ( ... )` within `.map()` which allows you to omit explicit returning.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Totally would be, but code cleanliness wasn't the issue or objective. I wanted to make it overtly clear to the OP that a value *must* be returned by ***explicitly*** returning it.

Comment: For OP [Arrow function syntax with parentheses instead of curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596873/arrow-function-syntax-with-parentheses-instead-of-curly-braces)