# What is the difference between using spread operator in brackets and without

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

today I encountered that it is impossible to set state in react native using old state value and then utilizing spread operator like this:

`setSomeValue(oldValue => {...oldValue, someField: 'newValue'})`

it is necessary to add parentheses:

`setSomeValue(oldValue => ({...oldValue, someField: 'newValue'}))`

and then everything works just fine.

What is the reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrow function without curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629962/arrow-function-without-curly-braces)

Comment: when you add parenthesis () means returning function data from a single line without writing return statement.

Comment: The first one doesn't actually return anything. The second one however is shorthand for `setSomeValue(oldValue => { return {...oldValue, someField: 'newValue'}; })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a block of arrow function using `{}`. So when you do `() => {}` you are not returning an object. You are returning nothing.

You can update this code to return an object as:

```
() => {
    return { someField: 'newValue' }
}
```

But JS provides a shortcut to use parenthesis `()` to create a expression and return it.

So, `() => ()` will return any expression inside second `()`. So when you do `() => ({ someField: 'newValue' })`, now you are returning an object directly without creating block and doing an implicit return.

Comment: Ahh yeah, now it sounds obvious, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
setSomeValue(oldValue => ({...oldValue, someField: 'newValue'}))
```

is equivalent to the following statement

```
setSomeValue(oldValue => {
    return {...oldValue, someField: 'newValue'};
})
```