# Cant map over array of Data because of wrong TypeScript type? - Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, types, setstate

I have tried so many ways to get the correct type for useState when setting an array of objects as the data.

I am pulling in data from an api and setting it using setState on a button press. But for the life of me cant work out how to define the type so typescript does not scream at me.

The error is being shown where I map the countryData in the JSX.

full Error is "Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactFragment'.
The types returned by 'Symbol.iterator.next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'IteratorResult<void, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<ReactNode, any>'.
Type 'IteratorYieldResult' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<ReactNode, any>'.
Type 'IteratorYieldResult' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)"

Code is below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `return` in your map function:

```
{countryData?.map((item : CountryData) => {
        return <CountryStats 
        countryCapital={item.capital}
        countryFlag={item.flags.png}
        countryName={item.name.common}
        countryPopulation={item.population}
        />
       })}
```

Comment: Thank you! - I have mapped components nearly all the time without using a return I wonder why it needs a return this time. I must being using a different format to how I do it previously.

Comment: How would I map it without using a return? as I also want to wrap it in a (showData &&} ternary so it only shows if there is data

Comment: Use parenthesis instead of curly braces. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629962/arrow-function-without-curly-braces

Comment: if you want to do it without a return you should remove `{}` and use `()` instead.

Comment: `array.map((item, idx) => (<div key={idx}></div>))`