# Valid component must be returned error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class App extends Component{
  render() {
    const numbers = {
      first : {
        name : "Dad",
        number : "1243342432",
        info : "Best dad ever!",
        birthDay : "4.2.1955"
      },
      second: {
        name : "Mom",
        number : "5435234523",
        info : "Best mom ever!",
        birthDay : "8.2.1967"
      },
      third: {
        name : "Martin",
        number : "5742253223",
        info : "Best friend Martin ever!",
        birthDay : ""
      }
    };  

    const FurtherInfo = (props) => {
      <div id={props.number}>
        <span className="contact__info"></span>
        <span className="contact__more"></span>
      </div>
    }

    const Name = (props) => {
      <p id="contact__name">{props.name}</p>
    }

    const Contant = (props) => {
        <li className="contact">
          <Name name={props.name}></Name>
          <FurtherInfo number={props.number}></FurtherInfo>
        </li>
    }

    const listItems = Object.values(numbers).map(
      person => <Contant name={person.name} number={person.number} ></Contant> 
    );

    return (
      <ul>{listItems}</ul>
    );
    }
}
```

But getting: `A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Looked through others problems with this error, unfortunately non of them matched my issue. Usually it has to do with not including () to `return` statement, however not in my case.

Anyone dealt with this before?

index.js is as always `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

Comment: Basic ES6: as soon as you open an arrow function with `{` you lose the ability to do an implicit return; you must either `return` explicitly, or drop the `{}` when they're not required, e.g., if the function contains a single statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curly Brackets in Arrow Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 6):

none of

```
const FurtherInfo = (props) => {
  <div id={props.number}>
    <span className="contact__info"></span>
    <span className="contact__more"></span>
  </div>
}

const Name = (props) => {
  <p id="contact__name">{props.name}</p>
}

const Contant = (props) => {
    <li className="contact">
      <Name name={props.name}></Name>
      <FurtherInfo number={props.number}></FurtherInfo>
    </li>
}
```

are actually returning anything (`void`). You need to use `()`s instead

```
const FurtherInfo = (props) => (
  <div id={props.number}>
    <span className="contact__info"></span>
    <span className="contact__more"></span>
  </div>
)
```

for example