# Why doesn't my arrow function return a value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have an arrow function that looks like this (simplified):

```
const f = arg => { arg.toUpperCase(); };
```

But when I call it, I get `undefined`:

```
console.log(f("testing")); // undefined
```

Why?

Example:

```js
const f = arg => { arg.toUpperCase(); };
console.log(f("testing"));
```

---

*(**Note:** This is meant to be a clean, canonical dupetarget for the **specific** issue with arrow functions above.)*

Comment: See also [Curly Brackets in Arrow Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35440265/1048572) and [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889450/1048572)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When you use the function body version of an arrow function (with `{}`), there is no implied `return`. You have to specify it. When you use the *concise* body (no `{}`), the result of the body expression is implicitly returned by the function.

So you would write that either with an explicit `return`:

```
const f = arg => { return arg.toUpperCase(); };
// Explicit return ^^^^^^
```

or with a concise body:

```
const f = arg => arg.toUpperCase();
```

Examples:

```js
const f1 = arg => { return arg.toUpperCase(); };
console.log(f1("testing"));

const f2 = arg => arg.toUpperCase();
console.log(f2("testing"));
```

---

*Slightly* tangential, but speaking of `{}`: If you want the concise arrow's body expression to be an object initializer, put it in `()`:

```
const f = arg => ({prop: arg.toUpperCase()});
```