# Why is my original state mutated when filtering with react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, redux

im using redux in an react app. Why is this filtering func mutating the original state.products? I cant understand why

```
state.products = [
   { 
      type: "one",
      products: [
         { active: true },
         { active: false }
     ]
  }
 ]

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 const test = state.products.filter((item) => {
   if(item.type === "one") {
     return item.products = item.products.filter((item) => {
       item.active
      });
    }
    return item;
  });

  return {
    machineSearchWeightRange: state.machineSearchWeightRange,
    filteredItems: test //This will have only products active
 };
}
```

filteredItems will have only products that is active but the state.products is also updated containing only active products when trying to filter on the same data again.

Suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're assigning to a property on an existing state item:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const test = state.products.filter((item) => {
    if(item.type === "one") {
      return item.products = item.products.filter((item) => { // <========== Here
        item.active
       });
     }
     return item;
   });

   return {
     machineSearchWeightRange: state.machineSearchWeightRange,
     filteredItems: test //This will have only products active
  };
}
```

Instead, create a *new* item to return. Also, it looks like you need `map` along with `filter`, and you're not actually *returning* `item.active` in your inner `filter` (see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value) for more there):

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const test = state.products.filter(({type}) => type === "one").map(item => {
    return {
        ...item,
        products: item.products.filter((item) => {
          return item.active;
        })
    };
  });

  return {
    machineSearchWeightRange: state.machineSearchWeightRange,
    filteredItems: test //This will have only products active
  };
}
```

---

Side note: This:

```
products: item.products.filter((item) => {
  return item.active;
})
```

can be simply:

```
products: item.products.filter(({active}) => active)
```