# update one field in React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My question is how to update one field in react state (if i have more than one)
e.g.:

```
class TestingClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          name: "",
          lastname: "something"
        };
    }
};
```

And now in some method i run from render()

```
someMethod = () => {
      this.setState(state => {
        const newName = state.name + " 0 ";
        return { newName };
      });
    };
```

And now the state will only have one field (name), lastname will disappear.
Or am i wrong... ?

Comment: The object returned by `setState` is merged with the old state.

Comment: Did you test it? If you run this code and use the React Dev Tools you will see that this works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And now the state will only have one field (name), lastname will disappear.

No, [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) merges the object you provide with the existing state. In your code, your state object will end up having `name`, `lastname`, and `newName` (because that's the name you've used in the object you return from the `setState` callback).

If you want to update `name`, you need to use the name `name` in the new object you're returning:

```
someMethod = () => {
  this.setState(state => {
    const name = state.name + " 0 ";
    return { name };
  });
};
```

---

Side note: That code can be more concise **if** you want, using a concise arrow function and destructuring:

```
someMethod = () => {
  this.setState(({name}) => ({ name: name + " 0"}));
};
```

or using just destructuring but keeping the function body on the arrow function:

```
someMethod = () => {
  this.setState(({name}) => {
    name += " 0";
    return { name };
  }
};
```

I'm not *advocating* it (minifying is for minifiers), but it's useful to know...

Comment: Okay, so the "someMethod" will know that i want to change only "name" ?
It will not behave in a such way that i passed "name" as "state" and now i can do some weird things?
And i've got second question - Do i need return statement in "someMethod" ? Or it works like that: If i have colon with the variable then i dont need return, but if i dont then i need it ? I'm pretty new in react and trying to understand it...

Comment: @emsiiggy - When you give an object to `setState`, it merges that object's properties with the current state. So yes, `someMethod` will change just `name` and leave other things alone. Re your second question: You have to return an object. All of the methods in the answer return an object. The one that doesn't have a `return` keyword in it is a *concise-form arrow function* (the first character after the `=>` isn't a `{`), and so it implicitly returns the result of the expression in it. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing this in `setState` your method works and will merge the updated `name` with the rest of your state.