# Trying to use dictionary look up to dynamically map options in a select drop down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have a react component that includes a dictionary of key/value pairs representing US state abbreviations for the key and their full name as the value like:

```
const states = {
  AL: "Alabama",
  AK: "Alaska",
  AZ: "Arizona",
  AR: "Arkansas",
  CA: "California"
}
```

I also have an API response that sends back a `state` as part of a nested `address` object as an abbreviation. So for California, the API returns `CA`

I'm trying to check the API response against my object and dynamically map only the US states that match what's in the dictionary to options in a select dropdown but I'm getting errors saying `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` for my initial function.

I've included the dictionary look up function as well as my component below.

`Dictionary lookup - causing the errors`

```
const activeStates = props.locations.map(x => {abbr: x.address.state; name: states[x.address.state]});
```

`React Component with select dropdown`

```
<select>
  <option>
    {Object.entries(activeStates).map((name, abbreviation) => <option key={abbreviation} value={abbreviation}>{name}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Very nearly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value (or maybe it even is one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a `{` immediately after the `=>`, your arrow function uses a *FunctionBody* form and the `{` and ending `}` are the function's block, not an object literal. So you have code in the function that looks like:

```
abbr: x.address.state; name: states[x.address.state]
```

(I'm slightly surprised you're getting an error for that; it looks like valid code using labels to me, but... Or perhaps the error is from the code block cited below.)

If you want to use the concise form, put `()` around the object literal:

```
const activeStates = props.locations.map(x => ({abbr: x.address.state; name: states[x.address.state]}));
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

You also have a couple of typos in your second code block, you don't have `)` to end the `map` call's argument list, and you don't have `}` to end the JSX expression. Fixing those:

```
<select>
  <option>
    {Object.entries(activeStates).map((name, abbreviation) => <option key={abbreviation} value={abbreviation}>{name}
  </option>))}
</select>
```

**But**, `Object.entries` gives you an array of `[key, value]` arrays, so your parameter list for `map` should be using destructuring rather than two parameters (I'd also probably avoid making it quite so long, but that's a matter of style) and they'd be in the opposite order:

```
<select>
  <option>
    {Object.entries(activeStates).map(([abbreviation, name]) => (
        <option key={abbreviation} value={abbreviation}>{name}</option>
    ))}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working it out by chaining a few mapping functions together with a filter like:

```
  let activeStates = props.locations.map(x => ({abbr: x.address.state, name: states[x.address.state]as string}));

  function getUnique(activeStates, comp) {

    const unique = activeStates
      .map(e => e[comp])
      // store the keys of the unique states
      .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)
      // eliminate the duplicate keys and store unique states
      .filter(e => activeStates[e]).map(e => activeStates[e]);
     return unique;
  }

  let uniqueStates = getUnique(activeStates, 'abbr')
```

A bit of a roundabout but it ended up working and now all the options are mapping correctly. Thank you T.J. for the great suggestions!