# JavaScript Arrow Function throws Undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below is my code for move all characters forward by one for a given string.

> ex. abc => bcd

```
    const moveCharForward = (str) => { 
      str
        .split('')
        .map(char => String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) + 1)).join('');
     }


console.log(moveCharForward('abcd'));
```

when I called the method it throws undefined.

I modified the code by removing the curly brackets like below.

```
    const moveCharForward = (str) => 
      str
        .split('')
        .map(char => String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) + 1)).join('');

console.log(moveCharForward('abcd')); //working correctly
```

Now when I called the method its working correctly.

I want to know why throws undefined when Im adding method implemetation inside the curly brackets?

Comment: You are missing a `return` in your `moveCharForward` function. JavaScript functions w/o an  explicit `return` statement return `undefined`. Arrow functions that do not use the block syntax, `{}`, are a special case that returns the last result.

Comment: You need the return sign in curly braces

Comment: It doesn't *throw* `undefined`, it *returns* `undefined`. (More accurately: Calling it results in `undefined`.)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen thanks.Now I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using arrow functions like this, if you don't use curly braces, then JavaScript implicitly returns the value following the arrow. However, if you do use curly braces, then JavaScript expects a block of code, in which there must be a `return` statement in order to return a value

Comment: This question is asked a **lot**. There's a well-established [dupetarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value) for it. No need to post further answers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just started to learn arrow functions in JavaScript.

Comment: @dasitha - The comment above isn't meant to criticize the question. It's to point out that posting an *answer* to it isn't how SO works. When there are already answers on SO, we point new questions at those, rather that cluttering up the site with 150 questions about the same thing with 300 different answers.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the curly braces you need the return keyword. Without curly braces the return is implied

Comment: This question is asked a **lot**. There's a well-established [dupetarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value) for it. No need to post further answers.