# React error [Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Today i'm trying to make a Sidebar by following a tutorial after many packages...

So tutorial link can be found at youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXa0f4-dWi4)

> Here is my code who react don't like:
>
> > ERROR:
> >
> > > Line 24:25:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

```
{SidebarData.map((item,index) => {
     <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
        <Link to={item.path}>
           {item.icon}
           <span>{item.title}</span>
        </Link>
     </li>
})}
```

> Full code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {List,X} from "react-bootstrap-icons";
import { SidebarData} from "./SidebarData";

function Sidebar(){

    const [sidebar,setSidebar] = useState(false)
    const showSideBar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar)

    return (
        <>
            <div className="navbar">
                <Link to='#' style={{fontSize:"50px"}}>
                    <List onClick={showSideBar}/>
                </Link>
            </div>
            <nav className={sidebar ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                <ul className="nav-menu-items">
                    <li className="navbar-toggle">
                        <Link to='#' className="menu-bars" style={{fontSize:"50px"}}><X /></Link>
                    </li>
                    {SidebarData.map((item,index) => {
                        <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                            <Link to={item.path}>
                                {item.icon}
                                <span>{item.title}</span>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    })}
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </>
    )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

> SidebarData.js items :

```
import React from 'react';
import {X, Tag, FileEarmarkPostFill,PersonBadge,CashStack,Tools} from 'react-bootstrap-icons'

export const SidebarData = [
    {
        title: 'Administration',
        path: '/admin',
        icon: <X />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: 'Category',
        path: '/admin/category',
        icon: <Tag />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: 'Product',
        path: '/admin/product',
        icon: <FileEarmarkPostFill />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: 'Order',
        path: '/admin/order',
        icon: <CashStack />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: 'User',
        path: '/admin/user',
        icon: <PersonBadge />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: 'Support',
        path: '/admin/support',
        icon: <Tools />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
]
```

I don't really know the error and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you point out the line of code which throws the error?

Comment: One issue with that code is that your `map` callback doesn't return anything. More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map function should return JSX code to work. When you are using curly braces you should use the keyword `return` or simply return the code by wrapping it inside parentheses.

example -

```
{SidebarData.map((item,index) => (
     <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
        <Link to={item.path}>
           {item.icon}
           <span>{item.title}</span>
        </Link>
     </li>
))}
```

```
{SidebarData.map((item,index) => return {
     <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
        <Link to={item.path}>
           {item.icon}
           <span>{item.title}</span>
        </Link>
     </li>
})}
```

Both will work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are not returning anything from `.map` Try this:

```
SidebarData.map((item,index) => (
     <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
        <Link to={item.path}>
           {item.icon}
           <span>{item.title}</span>
        </Link>
     </li>
))
```