# Math.random() generating same number when put in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm working on a react project in which I have to generate random ids so I made this function

```
const idGenerator = () =>{
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)
}
```

when I'm using it directly like this it works fine generates different ids

```
{ 
   id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) 
}
```

but when I make function and use it like this it generates the same id why is that?

```
const idGenerator = () =>{
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)
}
// using it to make an object
{
   id: idGenerator 
}
```

Comment: where do you make the object?

Comment: maybe use `return`?

Comment: `const idGenerator = () =>{ Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) }` will only produce `undefined` since you have no `return` statement. Either add `return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)` or remove the curly brackets around the body `{` and `}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't my arrow function return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value)

Comment: Also relevant [When should I use `return` in es6 Arrow Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889450)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried it also with an return statement?

```
const idGenerator = () =>{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)
}
```

Or shorter

```
const idGenerator = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
```

```js
const idGenerator = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);

let obj1 = {
   id1: idGenerator(),
   id2: idGenerator()
}

console.log(obj1);
```

Also you need to execute the function with parenthesis `()` otherwise your propertie will hold the reference to the function

Comment: I tried your code but it still was getting error then I put a parenthesis while using idgenerator it was working fine. Thanks :)