# Working with a array of objects in React. Iterating error saying I cannot use object, use array instead

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm working on a React portfolio project. I have an external data.js file with an array of objects, which I import into the JS file I'm working in. I want to iterate over the array and place each object into it's own div.

I already tried an If Loop and now working with Map(). This is my code:

```
const Project = () => {

    const ProjectItem = () => (
      ProjectenList.map(project => (
        <div key={project.id}>
          <div>{project}</div>
        </div>
      ))
    )


    return (
      <div className='project-kader'>
        <h1 className='title'><ProjectItem /></h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I don't get the problem of iterating trough an array of objects. This is the error:

**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {-list of keys-}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

I must overlook a simple thing, but I'm a little stuck at the moment :-)

Comment: Please show us what the contents of `ProjectenList` are. From the fact you're using `project.id` (and the error), we can guess that they're objects, but...?

Comment: Try to change your <h1> in this way: ```<h1>{ ProjectItem }</h1>```

Answer (score 2):

From the fact you're using `project.id` (and the error message from React), we can assume that `project` is an object, which means you're trying to use an object as a React child here:

```
<div>{project}</div>
```

The error is that you can't do that. Instead, use properties from the object to come up with how you want it displayed. For instance, if `project` has a `description` property:

```
<div>{project.description}</div>
```

Or if it has (say) a description and a number of days estimated for the project, you might do:

```
<div>{project.description} - {project.days} {project.days === 1 ? "day" : "days"}</div>
```

And so on. The fundamental thing is to provide React with something it can put in the DOM (loosely, "display"), such as strings, numbers, arrays, `true` (but not `false`)...

Comment: ProjectenList is a variable containing the array with objects (with their own properties). So indeed, it works when I use {project.id} for instance, but not when I only use {project}. This is the part I don't understand.

Comment: @Paul - You have to tell React what it is about the object you want to display in that `div`, what properties, etc. It's not all that different from if you were using the object in a string. If you did `const str = "The object is: " + project;`, you wouldn't get anything useful in the normal case (you'd get `The object is: [object Object]`). So as I've noted above, you have to use information from the object to show how it should be displayed in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return array from your `ProjectItem` i.e you need to do this:

```
const Project = () => {

    const ProjectItem = () => (
      ProjectenList.map(project => (
        <div key={project.id}>
          <div>{project}</div>
        </div>
      ))
    )


    return (
      <div className='project-kader'>
        <h1 className='title'>{ProjectItem()}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: The OP **is** returning the result of `map` (and changing it to the above would cause a syntax error). They're using `()`, not `{}`, in the arrow function, so the arrow function returns that expression's result. (It's a bit hard to read.) (Side note: If this *were* the problem, it would make the question a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value).)

Comment: Thanks! But I'm immediatly returning anything that's inside the arrow function with ( ) instad of { }.

Answer (score -1):

try JSON.stringy(project) like this or you should use your object property.Let's we say project has a property that called name

Here is a working example for you.

```
const Project = () => {

const ProjectItem = () => (
  ProjectenList.map(project => (
    <div key={project.id}>
      <div>{JSON.stringy(project)} || {project.name}</div>
    </div>
  ))
)


return (
  <div className='project-kader'>
    <h1 className='title'><ProjectItem /></h1>
  </div>
)
```

I hope it can work.

Answer (score -1):

you can use project as object into div element

```
const ProjectItem = () => (
        ProjectenList.map(project => (
            <div key={project.id}>
                <div>{project.text}</div>
            </div>
        ))
)
```