# Array.from method return an array with undefined values instead of real numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, fill

I wrote the following code:

```
let abcd= Array.from({length:7},(curr,i)=> { console.log(curr,i);  i+1;})
console.log(abcd); // returns [undefined *7]
```

I can't understand why *abcd* isn't initialized to 1 to 7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't my arrow function return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value, you are just incrementing it and simply not returning it, hence `undefined` is added.

```js
const result = Array.from({ length: 7 }, (curr, i) => i + 1 );
console.log(result)
```

Comment: lmam, the last language i have learned was kotlin. their the last statement in the block automatically returns the value. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The value return from the function passed to array.from is added to array. Here you are not returning anything so it automatically return `undefined` and you get array containing 7 `undefined`

```js
let abcd= Array.from({length:7},(curr,i)=> {
  console.log(curr,i); 
  return i+1;
})
console.log(abcd); // returns [undefined *7]
```

A better way for me to create array like this to use spread operator and `map()`

```js
let abcd = [...Array(7)].map((x, i) => i + 1)
console.log(abcd); // returns [undefined *7]
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer. Unfortunately i can approve only one answer, and you were the second one. Thanks again!!!