# While loop in a forEach function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, while-loop

I've faced a problem in js when looping over arrayitems within a forEach function.
I simply have an Array of IDs, where some IDs have less than 10 Characters, which I want to fill with "0" at the beginning.
Example:
`myArray = ["1234567890", "0123456789", "12345678"]`
In that case I want to fill up the last item with `"0" --> "0012345678"`.
Of course it's also possible in various other ways, but I simply don't get why it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
myArray.forEach(Id =>{
    while(Id.length < 10){
        Id= "0" + Id;
    }
})
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `Id= "0" + Id;`, you're just updating the **parameter** value. That parameter value isn't saved anywhere when you're done.

If you want to update the values in the array, either assign back to the existing array or (more commonly) create a new array via `map`:

```
myArray = myArray.map(Id => {
    while (Id.length < 10) {
        Id = "0" + Id;
    }
    return Id;
});
```

Or these days, you could use [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) instead of the `while` loop:

```
myArray = myArray.map(Id => Id.padStart(10, "0"));
```

Here's an example of assigning back to the original array, in case you wanted to do that:

```
myArray.forEach((Id, index) => myArray[index] = Id.padStart(10, "0"));
```

Live Examples:

```js
// Creating a new array (1)
let myArray1 = ["1234567890", "0123456789", "12345678"];
myArray1 = myArray1.map(Id => {
    while (Id.length < 10) {
        Id = "0" + Id;
    }
    return Id;
});
console.log(myArray1);

// Creating a new array (2)
let myArray2 = ["1234567890", "0123456789", "12345678"];
myArray2 = myArray2.map(Id => Id.padStart(10, "0"));
console.log(myArray2);

// Updating the existing array
let myArray3 = ["1234567890", "0123456789", "12345678"];
myArray3.forEach((Id, index) => myArray3[index] = Id.padStart(10, "0"));
console.log(myArray3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the faster answer, works now !
btw. what's the reason i don't need a return value in your second example wit the padStart function ?

Comment: @itsmeMarc - That's a concise-form arrow function (there's no `{` after the `=>`). The body consists entirely of a single expression, and that expression's result is the return value of the function. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value) (and in Chapter 3 of my recent book -- links in my profile if you're interested).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use forEach you must fetch the array also and change its content.

```
myArray.forEach((Id, index, arr) =>
{
    while(Id.length < 10){
        Id = "0" + Id;
    }
    arr[index] = Id;
});
```

Comment: @decpk thanks for the edit but you are wrong. The arg[index] = Id can be outside of the while loop

Comment: I just formatted your code not added anything

Comment: @decpk ok thx. too early in the morning ;)