# How to map through array of objects and create a new array of objects with a new added property using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i have array of objects like below,

```
const arr_obj = [ 
    {
        children: [{}],
        type: "type1",
        updated: "somevalue",
    },
    {
         children: [{}],
         type: "type2",
         updated: "somevalue",
     },
]
```

now i want to create a new array of object that will have each object as in arr_obj and also add new property "disabled" which is boolean value set to true if type is equal to "type2" if not set to false.

so the expected output is like below

```
const new_obj = [
    {
        children: [{}],
        type: "type1",
        updated: "somevalue",
        disabled: false,
    },
    {
        children: [{}],
        type: "type2",
        updated: "somevalue",
        disabled: true,
    },
]
```

I have tried like below

```
const new_obj = React.useMemo(() => {
    arr_obj.map((arr => ({
        ...arr,
        disabled: arr?.type !== "type2" ? false : true,
    }))
}, [arr_obj]
);
```

but when i log new_obj this is undefined. could someone help me with this. I am new to programming. thanks.

Comment: missing return statement ...?!

Comment: btw, naming an object array is misleading ...

Comment: Using `useMemo` here [probably isn't worth the effort](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not `return`ing the result of `arr_obj.map` so the function returns `undefined`.

Either

```
const new_obj = React.useMemo(() => {
  return arr_obj.map((arr) => ({
    ...arr,
    disabled: arr?.type !== "type2" ? false : true,
  }));
}, [arr_obj]);
```

or drop the braces:

```
const new_obj = React.useMemo(
  () =>
    arr_obj.map((arr) => ({
      ...arr,
      disabled: arr?.type !== "type2" ? false : true,
    })),
  [arr_obj],
);
```

Comment: [There's a well-established dupetarget for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value).