# Please explain to me. How does this Javascript code work step by step if that possible

Tags: javascript

n the function below, a comparison is made (finding out) which function called it. if the one is the most nested (internal), then a number is returned, and if the most external, then the function is executed.

```
var n = function(digit) {
  return function(op) {
    return op ? op(digit) : digit;
  }
};
```

these are variables to which function calls are assigned.

```
var zero = n(0);
var one = n(1);
var two = n(2);
var three = n(3);
var four = n(4);
var five = n(5);
var six = n(6);
var seven = n(7);
var eight = n(8);
var nine = n(9);
```

and this is the "operator" function

```
function plus(r) { return function(l) { return l + r; }; }
function minus(r) { return function(l) { return l - r; }; }
function times(r) { return function(l) { return l * r; }; }
function dividedBy(r) { return function(l) { return l / r; }; }
```

and this is the performance of functions, for the sake of which everything was written

```
one(plus(two())), 3);
seven(times(five())), 35);
four(plus(nine())), 13);
eight(minus(three())), 5);
```

that is, I understand how the code works in general, but I don’t understand the details, and I’m not able to consciously write such code myself because I don’t understand how it works in detail. This is where the problem is.
thanks in advance

Comment: Here's step by step stuff for 1+2: https://jsfiddle.net/pwjfeakv/

Answer (score 0):

The functions returned by `n` and `plus`, etc., are [*closures*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over the paramter value `n`, etc., were called with. For instance, with `n`:

```
var n = function(digit) {
  return function(op) {
    return op ? op(digit) : digit;
  }
};
// ...
var one = n(1);
var two = n(2);
```

So in the case of `two`, the function `n` returned (assigned to `two`) *closes over* the value of `digit` for the call (`2`), so it has access to it later.

Code calling `two` can do one of two things:

1. Call it with no arguments: `two()`
2. Call it with a function: `two(plus(one()))`

If `two` is called with no arguments, `op` will be `undefined`, so this:

```
return op ? op(digit) : digit;
```

becomes effectively

```
return digit;
```

So that means, `two()` returns `2`.

But if you pass a function into `two`, it calls that function with `2` as an argument. That's where things like `plus` come into it:

```
function plus(r) { return function(l) { return l + r; }; }
```

`plus` returns a function that closes over `r`. That function, when you call it with a value (`l`), returns the result of `l + r`.

So let's look at that in action: `two(plus(one()))`. Evaluation is inside out, so:

1. `one()` is called with no arguments, so it returns `1`; now we effectively have:

   ```
   two(plus(1))
   ```
2. `plus()` is called with `1` and returns `function(l) { return l + r; }` which is effectively `function(l) { return l + 1; }` (because `r` is `1`); so now we effectively have:

   ```
   two(function(l) { return l + 1; })
   ```
3. `two` is called with the function from Step 2 as `op`. Since it was given a function, `two` calls `op(2)` and returns its result.
4. `op` (the function from Step 2) returns `2 + 1`
5. The result is `3`.

Here's a version that makes it easier to see what's going on:

```js
const n = function(digit) {
    console.log(`n:       creating "digitFn" for ${digit}`);
    const digitFn = function(op) {
        if (op) {
            console.log(`digitFn: evaling op(${digit})`);
            const result = op(digit);
            console.log(`digitFn: returning ${result}`);
            return result;
        }
        console.log(`digitFn: no "op", returning ${digit}`);
        return digit;
    };
    return digitFn;
};
const plus = function(r) {
    console.log(`plus:    creating "opFn" for + ${r}`);
    const opFn = function(l) {
        console.log(`opFn:    evaling ${l} + ${r}`);
        const result = l + r;
        console.log(`opFn:    returning ${result}`);
        return result;
    };
    return opFn;
};

console.log("main:    Creating `one` and `two`");
const one = n(1);
const two = n(2);

console.log("main:    Doing `two(plus(one()))`");
console.log(two(plus(one())));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

This overall thing is called [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application): Taking a function that takes *N* arguments, "baking in" one or more of those arguments to produce a function that takes *< N* arguments (because some are already provided).

---

Side note: Because you'll see this in the wild, I'll just note that you'll probably see these written as *concise-form arrow functions*, which are written like this: `(params) => expression` (if there's only one parameter, the `()` are optional: `param => expression`). What makes those concise-form arrow functions is the fact that the first thing after the arrow (`=>`) is *not* a `{` ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value)). When called, a concise arrow function evaluates the expression and returns the result (implicitly, there's no `return` keyword in a concise arrow function). Those can *seem* complicated and intimidating at first, until you get used to reading them. Here's `n`:

```
// Does exactly what your original `n` does
const n = digit => op => op ? op(digit) : digit;
```

That breaks down like this:

- `digit => ____` is `n`, which returns the result of the expression `____`
- `op => ____` is the function `n` returns
- `op ? op(digit) : digit` is the expression the function created by `n` evaluates

Here's the full list:

```
const n = digit => op => op ? op(digit) : digit;

const zero = n(0);
const one = n(1);
const two = n(2);
const three = n(3);
const four = n(4);
const five = n(5);
const six = n(6);
const seven = n(7);
const eight = n(8);
const nine = n(9);

// Do exactly the same thing your original functions do
const plus      = r => l => l + r;
const minus     = r => l => l - r;
const times     = r => l => l * r;
const dividedBy = r => l => l / r;
```