# reduce in javascript using curly returns undefined

Tags: javascript

Just following mdn tutorial on reduce on javascript, Can someone please explain to me why below I cannot use the curly brackets around the callback?

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    
// 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
const initialValue = 0;
    
// expected output: 10
const sumWithInitialTest = array1.reduce( (pv, cv) => 
  { pv + cv }
)
    
console.log(sumWithInitialTest)
```

Obviously, without curly bracket, it works fine

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    
// 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
const initialValue = 0;
    
// expected output: 10
const sumWithInitialTest = array1.reduce( (pv, cv) => 
   pv + cv 
)
    
console.log(sumWithInitialTest)
```

Comment: Please read up on basic arrow function syntax. Trivial research would find e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45754957/3001761.

Comment: Because `{ pv + cv }` is equivalent to `{ pv + cv; return; }`

Answer (score 1):

Add return if you want to use curly bracket

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    
// 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
const initialValue = 0;
    
// expected output: 10
const sumWithInitialTest = array1.reduce( (pv, cv) => 
    { return pv + cv }
)
    
console.log(sumWithInitialTest)
```