# TinyMCE: Cannot read properties of undefined: reading "then"

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce

I'm using `images_upload_handler` to upload images directly to my own server. Pasted images work fine, but aren't uploaded to the server. When I try to upload a file, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVjwe.png)

Here's my `images_upload_handler` code:

```
images_upload_handler: (blobInfo, progress) => {
                            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                              const blob = blobInfo.blob();
                              const image = new FormData();
                              image.append("image", blob);
                              axiosClient
                                .post("/article/image", image, {
                                  headers: {
                                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                                  },
                                })
                                .then((response) => {
                                  alert(
                                    `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_PUBLIC_URL}${
                                      response.data.location
                                    }`
                                  );
                                  resolve(
                                    `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_PUBLIC_URL}${
                                      response.data.location
                                    }`
                                  );
                                })
                                .catch((error) => {
                                  reject("failed!");
                                });
                            });
                          },
```

I'm using [this documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/upload-images/), but I've also tried to use the syntax given in [this documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/#images_upload_handler). Neither work and I keep getting this error.

The images *do* upload, though. And I am definitely returning a location, because I am console logging the returned location and it all works.

I've tried removing any server-based image uploads, but that means I can't use the image tools plugin, apparently.
Is there anyway to use the imagetools plugin on pasted images *without* configuring a server image upload?

Comment: *"Pasted images work fine, but aren't uploaded to the server...."* *"The images do upload, though."* Which is it? In any case, I think the problem is that your function doesn't return anything (and so implicitly returns `undefined`), because you've used the full function body form of the arrow function (the first character after `=>` is `{`), but haven't used `return`. You need to either use the concise form body (no `{` after `=>`, and the body is just an expression) or you need to use the `return` statement; see [the linked question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/).