# What is the significance of using brackets inside an arrow function in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

**Given the following react-redux code:**

```
const TextListContainer = ({ items, actions }) => (
    <TextList items={items} actions={actions} />
)
```

Why are normal brackets used here instead of curly brackets?

---

To further illustrate my question:

**NORMAL FUNCTION:**

```
const someFn = something => {
    //...
}
```

**BRACE STYLE FUNCTION:**

```
const someFn = something => (
    //...
)
```

This style of code is copied from here: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/containers/App.js

Comment: Learn about destructuring or about how arrow function syntax actually works, depending on which braces you're asking about.

Comment: [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curly Brackets in Arrow Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions)

Comment: I know about destructuring and arrow syntax, how this is an example of destructuring?

Comment: It's not destructuring, it is shorthand for returning a value

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Patrick, would be good if people read the question first, will remove all mention of destructuring from the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`() => something`, where `something` doesn't start with `{`, returns `something`.

With `() => {`, `{` is interpreted as the start of a function body, so you have to explicitly `return` something. To get around this, e.g. if you wanted to return an object, you can use `(`:

```
() => ({ some object })
```

Using it in other situations is a question of consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this makes sense now, I am still unsure why everyone was pointing to destructuring in the comments above..

Comment: No problem, I guess they skimmed over your question and saw the `{ items, actions }` in the first example, which destructures the props object.

Answer (score 2):

Basically `{}` is used when there is function body and you need to return a particular value based on the computations in the function.
A simple example of a function to add 1 if value is more than 10 else subtract 1 .

```
(value) => {
  if(value > 10){
    return value + 1; 
  }
  return value - 1;
}
```

On the other hand if there is really a simple function like returning
a boolean value.you could do something like this:

```
(num) => (num > 100)
```

returns a boolean.
Simple and clean.

Comment: Thanks, really clean answer :)