# Default vue-cli lazy load code for route does not work when defined as lambda

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

I used `vue-cli` to scaffold a new Typescript project and specified it should include `vue-router`.

This auto-generated a `router/index.ts` with a router configuration that looked like this:

```
const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
 },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: () => { import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue') },
  }
]
```

This file compiles fine as one would expect. However, when I try to call the route using `<router-link>` the About page does not render. I can confirm the route is being called, because if I add a `console.log('x')` into the import lambda above, I see the 'x' in the console but the About component constructor is never called and the About  content is not rendered.

However, if I adjust the `index.ts` as follows (as per [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html)), then the route works correctly and displays the view:

```
const AboutRoute = () => import('../views/About.vue')

const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
 },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: AboutRoute,
  }
]
```

Can anyone explain why the second version works, but not the first as they seem equivalent to me.

Thanks
Ian

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curly Brackets in Arrow Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 1st solution doesn't work because it's not returning the import.

In Javscript when you add brackets `{ }` to a function, it's not going to return the result automatically, you need to add the `return` word yourself. So either don't add brackets or add `return`:

### Method 1:

```js
component: () => {
  return import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "about" */ 
    '../views/About.vue'
  )
}
```

### Method 2:

```js
component: () => import(
  /* webpackChunkName: "about" */ 
  '../views/About.vue'
)
```