# Javascript filter function must be always written on one line?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I spend some time figuring out what was the problem with this

```
arr.filter((order)=>{
   order.trackingNumbers.some((track)=>{
      track.number==search
   })
})
```

and then noticed that it works if is written in just one line

```
arr.filter(order=>order.trackingNumbers.some(track=>track.number==search))
```

why is that and is posible to write it on several lines?

Comment: It's the braces: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr.filter((order)=>{
   return order.trackingNumbers.some((track)=>{
      return track.number==search
   })
})
```

you can omit return keyword when you're omitting bracket thats why the single line works