# I've seen this promise code after a GET request: .then(resp => resp.body))

Tags: javascript, api, http, response

```
 .then(resp => resp.body))
```

This code is written after a GET request in a large Node app. I'm thinking it means take the received response and return the response.body? Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: resp itself returns the response if you need to get particular value , then you can access using property name

Comment: Yes; there's no other way to read it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curly Brackets in Arrow Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are reading it correctly.

```
// Traditional Function
function (a){
  return a + 100;
}

// Arrow Function Break Down

// 1. Remove the word "function" and place arrow between the argument and opening body bracket
(a) => {
  return a + 100;
}

// 2. Remove the body braces and word "return" -- the return is implied.
(a) => a + 100;

// 3. Remove the argument parentheses
a => a + 100;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very easy to follow. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Just for improving the answer,

.then(resp => resp.body)) will be converted to

```
.then(function(resp){
    return resp.body;
})
```