# why does Array.Protoype.every() returns false with curly braces but returns true without curly braces

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I encountered an issue while working on a project and I noticed that it was as a result of the curly braces in my function... quick example

```
const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const array2 = [2,4,6];

const isPresentInBothArrays1 = array2.every((number)=>{
   array1.includes(number);
});

console.log(isPresentInBothArrays1) //prints false;

const isPresentInBothArrays2 = array2.every((number)=>array1.includes(number));

console.log(isPresentInBothArrays2) //prints true;
```

why does isPresentInBothArrays1 **with curly braces** return false and IsPresentInBothArrays2 **without curly braces** return true?

Comment: Because that's how arrow functions work https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curly Brackets in Arrow Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions) and [Arrow function without curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629962/arrow-function-without-curly-braces)

Comment: Thanks...It certainly does answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the arrow function syntax, If you write something like this:

```js
(param1, param2) => {//some expression}
```

is equivalent to this:

```js
function f(param1, param2) {
   // some expression
}
```

and because it does not have an explicit return statement it will return `undefined` by default.

However, if you omit the curly brackets and put a single expression that would be a shortcut and will return the value of that expression as the return value of the function.

So as for your question in the first form, it will return `undefined` from the function which evaluates to `false` and is not what you desire, but the second form correctly returns a boolean indicating the existence of the value.

Comment: Its a clear duplicate, just flag –

Comment: @pilchard you're right, next time I guess.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `return` if you use curly braces:

```js
const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const array2 = [2,4,6];

const isPresentInBothArrays1 = array2.every((number)=>{
   return array1.includes(number);
});

console.log(isPresentInBothArrays1) //prints true;

const isPresentInBothArrays2 = array2.every((number)=>array1.includes(number));

console.log(isPresentInBothArrays2) //prints true;
```

Comment: Its a clear duplicate, just flag

Comment: @pilchard What makes you think that?

Comment: The fact that it is now closed as a duplicate ;)

Comment: Ohh, i thought you were talking about the answers. My bad :)

Answer (score 1):

If you omit curly braces, arrow function will implicitly return the result of the expression after the `=>`.

However, if you use curly braces, you'll need to write `return` in order to make it return something, otherwise, it will return `undefined`.

So, in this particular case, you'll need to write:

```js
const isPresentInBothArrays1 = array2.every(number => {
   return array1.includes(number);
});
```

In case you want to have curly brackets for whatever reason.

Comment: Its a clear duplicate, just flag –