# ES6 Arrow function syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried searching the web for an answer, or I may just be thinking about it too much. While watching some React videos I see devs using arrow functions two ways:

1. const name = () => {} -- here ending with curly braces
   and
2. const name = () => () -- here ending with parentheses

Is there a difference between the 2?

Comment: You use the second to return an object directly without a return statement

Comment: Gotcha thanks! This link also helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions

Answer (score -3):

The second will return the value of the expression inside the brackets after evaluation.

The first will require a `return` statement to return a value.