# Spread Operator for array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, setstate

**How to perform spread opration on salesuser array object. need to add  ..salesuserstargetAmount:500, in that object**

```
  {        
    "station": [
        {
            "stationname":"chennai",
            "stationtargetAmount":500,
            "salesusers":[
                {
                " salesusersname":"tester", 
                },         
         ]
        },
    {
            "stationname":"chennai22222",
           "stationtargetAmount":500,
            "salesusers":[
                {
                " salesusersname":"tester222222", 
                },         
         ]
        }
    ]
 }
```

**Tried with**

```
let  salesusertargetamt = "100"

 this.setState({
   salesusers: this.state.station.map((items) => {
   items.salesusers.map(el => (el.salesusersname !== "" ? { ...el, salesusertargetamt } : el))
  });
```

Comment: Be aware `map` returns the same number of items as the original array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curly Brackets in Arrow Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly braces (`{`) are tricky here because they both mean block of code and JavaScript object so you need to wrap them with `()`:

```js
let  salesusertargetamt = "100";

 let obj = {        
    "station": [
        {
            "stationname":"chennai",
            "stationtargetAmount":500,
            "salesusers":[
                {
                " salesusersname":"tester", 
                },         
         ]
        },
    {
            "stationname":"chennai22222",
           "stationtargetAmount":500,
            "salesusers":[
                {
                " salesusersname":"tester222222", 
                },         
         ]
        }
    ]
 };
 
 let result = obj.station.map(items => ({
    ...items,
    salesusers: items.salesusers.map(user => (user.salesusersname !== "" ? {...user, salesusertargetamt} : user ))
 }))
 

 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let  salesusertargetamt = "100"

 this.setState({
   salesusers: this.state.station.map((items) => {
    return items.salesusers.map(el => (el.salesusersname !== "" ? { ...el, stationtargetAmount: salesusertargetamt } : el))
  });
```

Comment: Please may you add some explanation? Why does this help? What did you change?

Comment: Well, you forgot to return an array inside the map arrow function block.

Comment: Take note of usernames. I'm not the asker.

Comment: If you want to update your answer, please [edit] instead of commenting.