# JavaScript filter method not giving unique result

Tags: javascript

i am trying to filter the unique ones from a given array using filter method but its throwing an empty array, here is the code

```js
function dual(a) {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    let unique = a.filter((val, index) => {
      a.indexOf(val) == index
    })
    return unique;
  }
}
console.log(dual([3, 1, 1, 2, 2])) //expected result [3,1,2] but showing []
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70865229/12057512. `const no_dupes = [...new Set(arr)];`

Comment: You're missing a `return` statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curly Brackets in Arrow Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to create a unique array:

```
const arr = [3,1,1,2,2]

var uniqueArray = [...new Set(arr)]

console.log(uniqueArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `return` statements from both your `function` and your `filter` array method.