# How to remove elements from array if not matching?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to delete all elements that matches `@b.com`, but it returns an empty array even if I remove the `!`, which leads me to think, I am doing something competently wrong.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```js
    const arr = ['a@a.com', 'b@b.com', 'c@c.com'];
    
    if (arr !== null && arr.length > 0) {
       const arr2 = arr.filter(e => {
          !e.match(/@b.com/);
       });
       console.log(arr2);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curly Brackets in Arrow Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions)

Comment: You need to `return !e.match(/@b.com/);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `return` statement:

```js
const arr = ['a@a.com', 'b@b.com', 'c@c.com'];

if (arr !== null && arr.length > 0) {
   const arr2 = arr.filter(e => {
      return !e.match(/@b.com/);
   });
   console.log(arr2);
}
```

One more thing, if you don't match by regex, you can just use [string.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
const arr = ['a@a.com', 'b@b.com', 'c@c.com'];

if (arr !== null && arr.length > 0) {
   const arr2 = arr.filter(e => {
      return !e.includes('@b.com');
   });
   console.log(arr2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget the ***return*** statement.

```js
const arr = ['a@a.com', 'b@b.com', 'c@c.com'];
const arr2 = arr?.length ? arr.filter((e) => !e.match(/@b.com/)) : [];
console.log(arr2);
```