# Use on parenthesis () or use curly brackets {} in react component

Tags: reactjs, anonymous-function, parentheses, curly-braces, array-map

I'm testing a react component, but have problems using an array map where is define an anonymous arrow function,  and after arrow (=>) I use curly brackets. Then the inside code could not be executed. The code call to other component called Star that use react icons to draw a star using FaStar.
Any way, I had to change the curly brackets for parenthesis and work with out problems.

Basically, my question what is the difference to use curly brackets or use parenthesis, with map and an arrow anonymous function?. When could be used parenthesis or curly brackets?

thanks for your help. Best Reagrds

This is the code not working (using curly brackets after the map's anonymous function)

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Star from './Star'

const StarRating = ({totalStars}) => {

  const [selectedStars, setSelectedStars] = useState(0)
  const starArray = arrayLenght => [...Array(arrayLenght)]
  console.log("totalStarts", totalStars)

  return (
    <>
      {starArray(totalStars).map((n, i) => {
        <Star
          key={i}
          selected={selectedStars > i}
          onSelect={() => setSelectedStars(i + 1)}
         />
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default StarRating
```

This code works fine (using parenthesis after the map's anonymous function)

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Star from './Star'

const StarRating = ({totalStars}) => {

  const [selectedStars, setSelectedStars] = useState(0)
  const starArray = arrayLenght => [...Array(arrayLenght)]
  console.log("totalStarts", totalStars)

  return (
    <>
      {starArray(totalStars).map((n, i) => (
        <Star
          key={i}
          selected={selectedStars > i}
          onSelect={() => setSelectedStars(i + 1)}
         />
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default StarRating
```

Comment: I suggest searching the site: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629962/arrow-function-without-curly-braces), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions). Please read through all of these threads thoroughly before claiming it's not a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrow function without curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629962/arrow-function-without-curly-braces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is related to the braces.
Without the braces a `return` is implicit while with the braces, you'll need to do an explicit `return`.

This below

```
   <>
      {starArray(totalStars).map((n, i) => {
        <Star
          key={i}
          selected={selectedStars > i}
          onSelect={() => setSelectedStars(i + 1)}
         />
      })}
    </>
```

Would be changed to this.

```
   <>
      {starArray(totalStars).map((n, i) => {
        return <Star
          key={i}
          selected={selectedStars > i}
          onSelect={() => setSelectedStars(i + 1)}
         />
      })}
    </>
```

Comment: Many thanks noted and understood. right now have problems to undestand the braces and return. Thanks