# on second loop arr.reduce accumulator is undefined and raise an error when trying to read something from it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array of Object, I'm trying to reduce it to age group people and how many of them voted.
on first loop it works good, on second loop accumulator becomes undefined and therefore I can't put anything in it.

this is my array of Object i'm looping over

```
var voters = [
  { name: 'Bob', age: 30, voted: true },
  { name: 'Jake', age: 32, voted: true },
  { name: 'Kate', age: 25, voted: false },
  { name: 'Sam', age: 20, voted: false },
  { name: 'Phil', age: 21, voted: true },
  { name: 'Ed', age: 55, voted: true },
  { name: 'Tami', age: 54, voted: true },
  { name: 'Mary', age: 31, voted: false },
  { name: 'Becky', age: 43, voted: false },
  { name: 'Joey', age: 41, voted: true },
  { name: 'Jeff', age: 30, voted: true },
  { name: 'Zack', age: 19, voted: false },
];
```

and this is my function with the default accumulator object

```
function voterResults(arr) {
  // your code here
  arr.reduce(
    (acc, person) => {
      const type =
        person.age >= 18 && person.age <= 25
          ? `Young`
          : person.age <= 55
          ? `Mid`
          : `Old`;

      if (person.voted) {
        acc[`num${type}People`]++;
        acc[`num${type}VotesPeople`]++;
      }
    },
    {
      numYoungVotesPeople: 0,
      numYoungPeople: 0,
      numMidVotesPeople: 0,
      numMidPeople: 0,
      numOldVotesPeople: 0,
      numOldPeople: 0,
    }
  );
}
```

I expect that every loop it will add the person to it's right age group and if he voted then it will add that to the age group voted counter.
error is can't read from undefined even tho on first loop it works just fine.

Comment: You have to return the accumulator for the next iteration.

Comment: @Andy even tho it's an arrow function? can you explain when I need to use return while using arrow functions?

Comment: Also, it seems that a filter first on person.voted would easily speed up the process.

Comment: @LightSkyLiam, if you use brackets, it will not return automatically. So () => element vs () => { return element }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions @LightSkyLiam

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code:

- in a `.reduce()` you need to return the accumulator (that is the reason for the error you reported)
- your `voterResults` function does not return the result
- you accumulator counts are off, `acc['num${type}People']++` needs to be outside the `if` statement

Corrected code:

```js
const voters = [
  { name: 'Bob', age: 30, voted: true },
  { name: 'Jake', age: 32, voted: true },
  { name: 'Kate', age: 25, voted: false },
  { name: 'Sam', age: 20, voted: false },
  { name: 'Phil', age: 21, voted: true },
  { name: 'Ed', age: 55, voted: true },
  { name: 'Tami', age: 54, voted: true },
  { name: 'Mary', age: 31, voted: false },
  { name: 'Becky', age: 43, voted: false },
  { name: 'Joey', age: 41, voted: true },
  { name: 'Jeff', age: 30, voted: true },
  { name: 'Zack', age: 19, voted: false },
];

function voterResults(arr) {
  // your code here
  return arr.reduce(
    (acc, person) => {
      const type =
        person.age >= 18 && person.age <= 25
          ? `Young`
          : person.age <= 55
          ? `Mid`
          : `Old`;

      acc[`num${type}People`]++;
      if (person.voted) {
        acc[`num${type}VotesPeople`]++;
      }
      return acc;
    },
    {
      numYoungVotesPeople: 0,
      numYoungPeople: 0,
      numMidVotesPeople: 0,
      numMidPeople: 0,
      numOldVotesPeople: 0,
      numOldPeople: 0,
    }
  );
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(voterResults(voters), null, '  '));
```

Output:

```
{
  "numYoungVotesPeople": 1,
  "numYoungPeople": 4,
  "numMidVotesPeople": 6,
  "numMidPeople": 8,
  "numOldVotesPeople": 0,
  "numOldPeople": 0
}
```